# Legend positions with pairs plot r

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot several variables and their respective correlation coefficients using the function `pairs()`.

It works well, though I would like to put all the axes' legends on the bottom and left side of the plot.
By default, they are changing side every two plots as you can see on this example:

```
pairs(~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris)
```

If anyone has an answer with and without `ggplot2` R package, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GGally`

`library(GGally)
ggpairs(data=iris)`

[image]

Or just the continuous columns

`ggpairs(data = iris[, 1:4])`

[image]

Comment: I saw that package and it seems good but I am struggling to install it in Rstudio. It has a dependency with "grid" and this one has been archived...

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry I don't use RStudio so will have to leave that for someone else.

Comment: The solution is interesting, but it needs some manipulations to be nice (like `axisLabels = "internal"`). It's quite a complicated object.

Comment: An answer with `pairs()` function has been given [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680783/how-can-i-change-the-axis-position-for-pairs)